# Image not displaying after picking one out from camera roll, store inputted image in array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, uiimage

Okay. First off, I'm sorry for the long question. My problem: I have the code to search for image in a camera roll or take one, and then store that in a `UIImage`. However, it is not displaying the image on the `NewPersonViewController`. Second, I want to append that saved image, `image`, to an empty array of `UIImages` that I created, and I don't know how. Snippets of my code:

```
var image:UIImage?
var Images:[UIImage] = []
//new snippet
Images.append(image!)
//another snippet
func updateDisplay(){
        if let mediaType = lastChosenMediaType{
            if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as NSString{
                imageView.image = image!
                imageView.hidden = false
                if moviePlayerController != nil{
                    moviePlayerController!.view.hidden = true
                }
            }else if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as NSString{
                if moviePlayerController == nil{
                    moviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: movieURL)
                    let movieView = moviePlayerController!.view
                    movieView.frame = imageView.frame
                    movieView.clipsToBounds = true
                    view.addSubview(movieView)
            }
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    lastChosenMediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String
    if let mediaType = lastChosenMediaType{
        if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as NSString{
            image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        }
        else if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as NSString{
            movieURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
        }
    }
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
    }
```

`Images.append(image!)` compiles, but gives this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.`

Really appreciate it :) Side note: I am new to swift.

Comment: where does `image` come from? i can find neither definition nor declaration...

Comment: Edited it to show def and dec. Sorry about that! @luk2302

Comment: i am confused: where is `Images.append(image!)` written? when is it called? when is `updateDisplay` called?

Comment: Images.append() is called when a button is pressed (an action, basically). updateDisplay() is called in override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)

Comment: did you try to append the image in "imagePickerController" after image = info[.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to append the image to your array when you get the image like so.

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    lastChosenMediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String
    if let mediaType = lastChosenMediaType{
       if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as NSString{
          let pickImg = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
             Images.append(pickImg)
             imageView.image = pickImg //set the imageView image.
      }
      else if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as NSString{
          movieURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
      }
  } 
 picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

here is code taken from my project that works.

```
 var newImage : UIImage?
 var Images:[UIImage] = []

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as String
    if mediaType == "public.image" {
        // Media is an image
        newImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage!
        println("update imgPreview")
        imgPreview.image = newImage
        Images.append(newImage!)

    } else if mediaType == "public.movie" {

    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

here is how I call the image picker

```
func pickPhoto() {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as NSString]
    //imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but the error is actually fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Images.append(image). Xcode forces me to add an '!' to the end of image, and that's the problem.

Comment: Thats wierd, In the code I provided it crashes at the line "Images.append(pickImg!)" ? I just ran it in my project that pulls an image from the camera roll with no crashes.

Comment: can you add the code where you call the imagePicker?

Comment: @richbrz, did my code/answer help you any. Are you still stuck?

Comment: @richbrz, if my answer solved your problem can you please mark it as accepted. If you are still stuck, let me know where you r problems are and I can try to help you.